# How to link extraterrestrial animal names from other language with terrestrial languages?

Tags: translation

As title states; how to name extraterrestrial fauna/flora to human languages, would reffering to animals similar to cows as to cows and to plant that bears round red fruits as to apple be linguisticly acceptable? Or maybe new words would have to be put in place to describe those creatures?

Comment: This is primarily opinion-based, and probably should be closed on that basis. This is not a new problem, either; there's plenty of SF where this has had to be done. Each author has done what has seemed best to him/her, ranging from making up nonsense words, to using terrestrial names based on appearance or behavior, to using _modified_ terrestrial names based on appearance or behavior, to ....

Comment: Oh, I did not know it had such obvious resolution. So all are correct? Each one will be accepted?

Comment: Karol, you're the creator, you can do whatever you want! :)

Comment: @KarolOfGutovo If you're looking for what other constructed languages do (along the lines of jknappen's answer), you could edit your question to ask how other conlangs deal with this

Comment: There is natlang precedent: consider the Tasmanian wolf and tiger.

Answer (score 3):

I think, the more generic a term is, the better you can use a known term in your native language. The more specific a term is, the greater is the need for some circumlocution or some conlang term.

**Examples:** Specific kinds of flowers and trees in Tolkien's "Lord of the Rings" have constructed names like *mallorn*, *niphedril*, or *simbelmyne*. He consistently used *pipe-weed* (the word *tobacco* is used by the narrator, but not in dialogues). Already on the level of genera, Tolkien uses terms like *pine tree*, *oak*, ... and of course there is *grass*, there are *trees*, there are *horses* and so on.

Whether you want to call some space creatures "cows" depends on the picture the word "cow" evokes and the uses of cows (Do they give milk and flesh? Can you use oxen for ploughing or driving a cart?) in your fictional culture.

Comment: Tolkien mentions horses and grass and so on because his Middle-earth is in the distant past of *our* world, in which those plants &c that have unfamiliar names are now extinct.